# Trouble implementing IComparable<T> in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, icomparable

I'm trying to sort an array in Unity by name, using `Array.Sort()`.

I've been reading as much as I can but still can't adapt it into my little project here. Here is what I have so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class UIController : MonoBehaviour, IComparable<Slot>
{
    public static UIController instance;
    public Text uiMessageBox;
    public Slot[] slots;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = this;
        else
            Destroy(this);

        DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

        slots = FindObjectsOfType<Slot>();
        Array.Sort(slots, ); // HELP: NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE
    }

    public int CompareTo(Slot other)
    {
        return this.name.CompareTo(other.name);
    }
}
```

Note, I deleted the parts I think are irrelevant in this class (such as the code that displays a message string on screen etc).

ALSO NOTE: I implement here `IComparable<Slot>` but I also tried it with `IComparable<UIController>`. (like I say, I've seen lots of examples here and other websites, but cannot quite get it to work in my code.)

Comment: I think you also need to implement the non-generic `IComparable` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: ok i will try, but actually i think i already did that on my first try. But will try again. Ta

Comment: Use the [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Sort__1___0___System_Comparison___0__) that accepts a lambda. Otherwise, move the `CompareTo` method to a separate class and pass `new ThatClass()` to `Array.Sort`.

Comment: IComparable<T> means you can compare this to a T. You'd need to have Slot implement IComparable<Slot> or make (for instance - I'd create a separate SlotComparer class probably) your UIController class implement IComparer<Slot>.

Comment: when I implement the generic one, the overriden method has parameter type 'Object'. I'm not usually dealing with those with Unity. How could I access the 'name' from that (the name shown in Heirarchy of Unity if you know what I mean). Thanks

Comment: @BigTLarrity Forget my comment, Wai Ha Lee got it right

Comment: IComparer<Slot> . Thanks I will try it

Comment: So it now has two parameters. I guess that is each slot in the array to check and IComparer<Slot> actually now takes both as parameters. I think I understand now, as the class implementing (ie. UIController) isn't the thing getting compared and so of course the method would need two slots at a time to compare to. Im adding this code, hopefully it will work: ....     public int Compare(Slot x, Slot y)
    {
       return x.name.CompareTo(y.name);
    }

Answer (score 2):

Why not use delegate form?

```
Array.Sort(slots, (slot1, slot2) => slot1.name.CompareTo(slot2.name));
```

If you still want to implement the IComparable interface, you must write it inside the **Slot** class.

And you can also implement [IComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) interface in any class.

```
class AnyClass : IComparer<Slot>
{
    public int Compare(Slot slot1, Slot slot2)
    {
        return slot1.name.CompareTo(slot2.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG! thanks for this, but simulataneously I just fixed it  (thanks for Wai Ha Lee mainly). I was able to keep it all within my UIController class, which is great. I will post it as an answer to demonstrate.   ..thanks all !

Comment: @shingo, `Array.Sort(slots, (slot1, slot2) => String.Compare(slot1.Name, slot2.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));` will be better!

Comment: I've used delegate and that lambda function sign before a fair few times but it was a long time ago and I forgot most of how to use them. Its definitely something i need to study some more to get better understanding and use from . Cheers

Comment: I think the first override form is fastest to write, if you need sort at only one place. ヽ(✿ﾟ▽ﾟ)ノ

Answer (score 1):

I was able to keep the code within my UIController class which is how I imagined it would be (since I built the array of slots there , it felt right for me to sort it there also.)

Here's how its done:

```
public class UIController : MonoBehaviour, IComparer<Slot>
{
public static UIController instance;
public Text uiMessageBox;
public Slot[] slots;


private void Awake()
{

    slots = FindObjectsOfType<Slot>();
    Array.Sort(slots, this); // i just passed 'this' as the IComparer parameter :)

}

public int Compare(Slot x, Slot y)
{
   return x.name.CompareTo(y.name);
}
```

}

Comment: Haha! This is the solution I was writing for you! :)

Comment: lol , sorry to beat you to it lol, and thanks anyway for the help! (I'm sure I'll need more soon haha :P)